# How to reproduce java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe

Tags: java, unit-testing, sockets, testing, serversocket

I need to right test that ensures that i fixed `java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe`. How to reproduce it if I have socket in java code?

Comment: You mean "handle" `SocketException`? You can't "fix" it.

Comment: Yes, handle it. Thanks)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you want to reproduce it on a unit test, you should use Mockito framework to reproduce this exception.

```
doThrow(new SocketException()).when(mockedObject.methodReturningVoid(...))
```

You can find more information  [here](http://site.mockito.org)

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to deal with unit tests though thats an awesome answer and I wasnt even aware of Mockito - simple solution though drastic is stop the application you're connecting to or temporarily disable your network device from your dev box.  I've used both.

Comment: That's not an automatic move.

Comment: I didnt understand your comment at first, but maybe your question is just a tiny bit unclear - if you meant automatically test it then may I suggest updating your question just a little bit